# Pose mode- can't change transform location of root bone?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I'm able to rotate and scale the root bone of my armature in order to affect my model, but changing its position does not appear to do anything. The location appears to be changed, looking at the bone's transform, but it does not visually affect anything.
-location is *not* locked
-Auto IK is *not* on
-manipulate center points is *not* selected
-duplication in object properties is set to none

[image: changed x pos to 9999, no visual difference]

[image]

Comment: There will be a constraint on the bone with "Transform" unchecked, which is why the transform value changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your file this problem is because the root bone `Bone.27` is set to `Connected`. You need to unset this. To do this follow the below steps:

1. Switch to Edit Mode
2. Select the root bone `Bone.27`
3. Go to the Bone tab in the properties window
4. Uncheck the `Connected`check box in the relations panel

[image]

This will fix the problem and you will be able to grab the root bone and move the character using it as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]